# Resize / partition at beginning of drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, 15.04

Im trying to resize up my root linux partition as im running out of space on it, however im not sure how i would do so with the partition being at the beginning of the drive.
[Disk Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Dps.png)

EDIT: This question is not specific to 15.04, i would have the same problem if on the latest 17.04

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice.

Comment: I would say move/resize the other partitions, but Windows is touchy about where its partitions start (and this is why I always install Windows at the start of the drive). You might want to move some folders (e.g. /home, /usr) into their own partitions.

Comment: In Windows use Disk Management to shrink the large parition by, lets say 50GB. Then boot an Ubuntu Live USB, start `gparted` to move the 3rd partition to the right), move the 2nd partition to the right. You now can increase the 1st partition.

Comment: Another option is to shrink the 3rd partition, then create a partition in the unallocated space, mount it in your Ubuntu and copy data files to it. Like wjandrea mentioned Windows can be quirky if you move its partitions.

Comment: @WillemK use the answers pls

Comment: If you can show me the current-window-only screenshot of gparted, I can make some recommendations for you.

Comment: this is in headless.

Comment: That doesn't tell me the whole story. A gparted screenshot would help me. Oh... is this a headless computer? Is that what you mean? Did you install Windows after you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: ubuntu server 15.04, windows was pre-installed

Comment: Then tell me how you installed Ubuntu server. I ask these questions because you've got a tricky situation, that if not handled well, could cause Windows not to boot, and require the use of a Windows install/repair disc. Do you have one of these? Do you also have a Ubuntu Live DVD?

Comment: It was installed from a live usb to a recovery partition that i removed for space that was at the beginning of the drive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58162/discussion-between-craftxbox-and-heynnema).

Comment: Just noticed you have Ubuntu 15.04, which hit EOL on Feb 4 2016. You will need to switch to a supported release, so maybe you'd rather reinstall Ubuntu at the end of the drive instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: @DavidFoerster No, this question involves resizing a partition that is behind the partition being shrank.

Comment: @craftxbox: The on-disk order of the partitions to grow and shrink doesn't matter at all. Use GParted to first shrink one and then grow the other partition as described in the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular partition reconfigure is especially tricky, and there are a number of ways to do it, and a number of ways to muck it up. I make no guarantees on success!

Warning... have good backups in case something goes wrong! You've been warned!

**As per our discussion in chat...**

You'll need:

1. a Windows install/repair DVD/USB
2. a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB

**The short answer is...**

Using Windows Disk Manager application...

- you'll need to shrink the left side of partition 3, if possible
- otherwise shrink the right side of partition 3 and then move partition 3 right
- Windows will probably not boot now
- use Windows install/repair DVD/USB to fix Windows boot problem
- move partition 2 to the far right, leaving unallocated space to its left
- Windows may not boot again
- use Windows install/repair DVD/USB to fix Windows boot problem

Using Ubuntu Live DVD/USB...

- start `gparted`
- right-click on sda1 (partition 1) and choose **resize**
- drag the right-side of sda1 to the far right
- click OK, then the Accept icon
- GRUB may need to be reinstalled, because of the Windows repairs

Comment: @craftxbox were my steps close to what you ended up having to do? Please give me some details.